# Combine Weaviate databases with different schemas

Tags: weaviate

I currently have a Weaviate database that contains 12 schemas and another which contains 10 schemas. Is it possible to just take the data for the 10 schemas and put them into the other database? If so, what is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can export all collections from one database schema and import them into another Weaviate database. (A bit of terminology: the Weaviate **schema** contains **class** definitions, and a **collection** consists of all objects class of the same class.) Since you haven't mentioned a specific programming language, here's a solution in pseudocode / Python.

First you need to initialize the clients for the source and target databases, say `source_db_client` and `target_db_client`.

Then you need to [get the schema](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/configuration/schema-configuration#review-schema) of the source database (the one with 10 collections in your case).

```py
schema = source_db_client.schema.get()
```

Then for each class in the schema (`for c in schema['classes']`),

1. [Fetch the class definition](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/manage-data/read-all-objects#fetch-the-schema) from the schema

```py
class_def = source_db_client.schema.get(c['class'])  # the class name
```

2. Recreate the class in the target database

```py
target_db_client.schema.create_class(class_def)
```

3. [Copy the objects](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/manage-data/read-all-objects#restore-to-a-target-instance) to the target instance using the [Cursor API](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/api/graphql/additional-operators#cursor-with-after) and [batching](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/api/rest/batch#batch-create-objects), skipping any cross-references (they require separate handling).

Python code could look like this:

```py
import weaviate

source_db_client = weaviate.Client('http://localhost:8080')

target_db_client = weaviate.Client('http://localhost:8081')

batch_size = 100

schema = source_db_client.schema.get()

for c in schema['classes']:
    class_name = c['class']
    class_def = source_db_client.schema.get(class_name)
    target_db_client.schema.create_class(class_def)

    # Skip copying cross-reference properties
    class_properties = [prop['name'] for prop in class_def['properties'] if prop['dataType'] not in [['crossReferencedClass1'], ['crossReferencedClass2'], ...]]
    cursor = None

    with target_db_client.batch(batch_size=batch_size) as batch:
        # Batch import all objects to the target instance
        while True:
            # From the SOURCE instance, get the next group of objects
            query = (
                source_db_client.query.get(class_name, class_properties)
                .with_additional(['id vector'])
                .with_limit(batch_size)
            )
            if cursor is not None:
                query = query.with_after(cursor)
            results = query.do()

            if 'errors' in results:
                raise Exception(results['errors'])

            # If empty, we're finished
            if len(results['data']['Get'][class_name]) == 0:
                break

            # Otherwise, add the objects to the batch to be added to the target instance
            for retrieved_object in results['data']['Get'][class_name]:
                new_object = dict()
                for prop in class_properties:
                    new_object[prop] = retrieved_object[prop]
                target_db_client.batch.add_data_object(
                    new_object,
                    class_name=class_name,
                    vector=retrieved_object['_additional']['vector']
                )

            # Update the cursor to the id of the last retrieved object
            cursor = results['data']['Get'][class_name][-1]['_additional']['id']
```

You can find equivalent TypeScript code in the Weaviate documentation under [How-to: Manage data -> Read all objects -> Restore to a target instance](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/manage-data/read-all-objects#restore-to-a-target-instance).